# lookup a table with range to populate an attribute

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, subquery

I have a requirement where I have two tables as below:

table named T1:

```
+-----------+
| days rate |
+-----------+
|         2 |
|        12 |
+-----------+
```

and table named T2:

```
+-------------+-------------+------+
| lower_range | upper_range | rate |
+-------------+-------------+------+
|           0 |           5 |    1 |
|          10 |          15 | 0.75 |
+-------------+-------------+------+
```

I would like to update "rate" on T1 by referring to T2 using days by determining which bucket it falls to so the expected output would be:

```
+------+------+
| days | rate |
+------+------+
|    2 |    1 |
|   12 | 0.75 |
+------+------+
```

Comment: Why do you have T2 in the first table as days ? What does a T2 value represent or is it just a typo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
update t1
    set rate = (select t2.rate from t2 where t1.days >= t2.lower_range and t1.days <= t2.upper_range);
```

If you only want to set values that match, then use `where` as well:

```
update t1
    set rate = (select t2.rate from t2 where t1.days >= t2.lower_range and t1.days <= t2.upper_range)
    where exists (select 1 from t2 where t1.days >= t2.lower_range and t1.days <= t2.upper_range);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, consider using a correlated subquery:

```
update t1
set rate = (
    select t2.rate
    from t2
    where t1.days between t2.lower_range and t2.upper_range
)
```

You might need to adjust the inequalities on the boundaries according to your actual use case. The above assumes that they are inclusive on both sides, but you could also want something else, like inclusive on the lower end and exclusive on the upper end:

```
    where t1.days >= t2.lower_range and t1.days < t2.upper_range
```

If you don't want to update rows that have no match in `t2`, then you can filter with `exists`:

```
update t1
set rate = (
    select t2.rate
    from t2
    where t1.days between t2.lower_range and t2.upper_range
)
where exists (
    select 1
    from t2
    where t1.days between t2.lower_range and t2.upper_range
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
merge into t1 trg
using
(
    select  lower_range, upper_range, rate
    from    t2
) src
on ( trg.days between src.lower_range and src.upper_range )
when matched then update
set trg.rate = src.rate
where lnnvl(trg.rate = src.rate);
```